# The installation window don't show a root file system for choose in the installation of Ubuntu, the manual didn't help me

Tags: system-installation, root

First of all, I have a new laptop Acer Aspire A315-53-386P with Windows 10. I was starting to install Ubuntu in the computer and then

[image]

I didn't understand the problem, so I investigated and I erased the secure boot and nothing. I want to erase Windows and install Ubuntu.

I read many sites, included [How to use manual partitioning during installation?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/343268/how-to-use-manual-partitioning-during-installation/343352), but they didn't helped me, all of them say me about a step 4, but my step 4 is this:

[image]

You must know that I am some beginner so really, any idea is useful.

Comment: @mook765 I edited the question because it didn't help me

Comment: The publication is updated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I read this 2 forums and I found the solution

- [Empty partition menu when installing 14.04 - AskUbuntu](https://askubuntu.com/a/580577/908039)
- [[SOLVED] Clean Installation [Archive] - Ubuntu Forums](https://ubuntuforums.org/archive/index.php/t-1508043.html)

Then I wrote in the terminal

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ sudo dmraid -Er /dev/sda
```

Then the terminal show me a message like `Do you really want to erase "isw" ondisk metadata on /dev/sda ?`, I wrote `y` (yes) and enter. This works and I can see the partition menu with normality. I don't know why this works, but did it.

Comment: Add command didn't work on mine. It threw, "no block devices found" message because there is no /dev/sda drive.