# Can't install ubuntu (linux) on SSD, ssd not detected

Tags: uefi, raid, ahci

I added an adata sx6000 lite SSD to my laptop (aspire 3 A315-55g-74nf).
Now I want install linux on ssd but ubuntu can not detect my ssd.
When I change SATA mode to AHCI I can't access boot and I have to press and hold power button for 15 seconds to reset bios.
What should I do for install Linux on my SSD?
Thanks

Comment: What release of Ubuntu did you try?  We currently have no idea as to what age of software stack you tried (specific details allow us to understand).  Desktop? Server? image using GA or HWE kernel?  The more you tell us, the more help we can provide

Comment: Have you updated UEFI? And SSD firmware? Acer Begins Publishing UEFI Firmware Updates For Linux Users On LVFS For Fwupd,  Aspire A315 laptop first
https://www.phoronix.com/scan.php?page=news_item&px=Acer-Updates-On-LVFS And you need AHCI. https://askubuntu.com/questions/1167506/the-installation-window-dont-show-a-root-file-system-for-choose-in-the-installa & similar: 
https://askubuntu.com/questions/1211911/cannot-install-ubuntu-on-acer-aspire-a515-54g-laptop-hard-drive-not-detected

Comment: I used ubuntu 18 desktop, and manjaro 20, I bought this laptop new, my laptop is core i7 10th, 2gb nvidia mx230, 8 GB ddr4 ram, and I added an adata sx6000 lite m2 ssd recently

Comment: I used this link https://askubuntu.com/questions/1211911/cannot-install-ubuntu-on-acer-aspire-a515-54g-laptop-hard-drive-not-detected but when I changed it to AHCI I see black screen, I can't access boot and I should press and hold power button for 15 second to reset boot to default settings