# Can't install Kubuntu or any other linux

Tags: system-installation

Specs:

- model: ACER Aspire 3 NX.HVUEU.01A
- CPU: Ryzen 5 3500u
- GPU: AMD Ryzen 5 3500U with Radeon Vega Mobile GFX
- OS: preinstalled Windows 10

This is the point where my laptop freezes:

[image]

And this might be my main problem:

[image: And this might be my main problem]

Comment: Have you updated UEFI and if SSD, SSD firmware? Changed RAID/Intel RST to AHCI? Issues with Acer common across many models. Acer Aspire A315-53-386P remove RAID from drive
https://askubuntu.com/questions/1167506/the-installation-window-dont-show-a-root-file-system-for-choose-in-the-installa & http://askubuntu.com/questions/627416/acer-aspire-e15-will-not-dual-boot & https://askubuntu.com/questions/1217061/installation-on-acer-swift-5-freezes-no-partitions-shown

Comment: Did all the thing.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem as you. I finally could boot KALI distro (in live first, then installing it completely). To do that, I changed manually in the `GRUB.CFG` file the boot options, adding the following ones:

```bsh
noeject noautomount acpiphp.disable=1 pcie_aspm=off nvme_core.default_ps_max_latency_us=14000
```

It worked!

I need to thank all the users of various forum who gave some piece of information.

What I understood is that the specific model of SSD Drive (a Western Digital SSD drive) was not recognized.