# Please help me install Ubuntu on my Acer Aspire 3

Tags: boot, dual-boot, partitioning, acer, aspire

I'm fairly new to Linux, I've used it before on VMs and used it once in a dual boot about 3 years ago.
My issue now though is that when I try to install Linux on my laptop, it doesn't detect any available storage device or partitions. I've looked on numerous sites for a solution but none of them have worked, or have given a solution that doesn't work with my device. My device specs are an AMD Athlon Silver 3050U, 12Gb DDR4 2400Mhz RAM, and an m.2 SN520 128Gb SSD. I believe I've done the correct steps in installing Ubuntu e.g. creating a separate partition to install Ubuntu on.
Here's a picture of what I'm getting when I go to install Ubuntu.[as you can see I have no options, when clicking next I just get a message saying no root directory](https://i.stack.imgur.com/egoAW.jpg)

I will be very grateful if anyone can help me get a solution.

Comment: Try choosing different devices by clicking on dropdown box, like /dev/sda

Comment: Tried that, nothing drops down. However last night I found a thread on Acer support which stated that the latest series of Acer laptops don't support Linux too well.https://community.acer.com/en/discussion/589603/linux-live-usb-doesnt-detect-hdd-on-aspire-3-a315-56

Comment: Have you updated UEFI and SSD firmware. And new systems need AHCI mode for drives, not RAID/Intel RST. But if using Windows you must first install Windows AHCI driver or Windows will not work.Acer Swift 5 (2019) ctrl-s  in UEFI required to be able to change to AHCI mode.
https://askubuntu.com/questions/1217061/installation-on-acer-swift-5-freezes-no-partitions-shown & https://askubuntu.com/questions/1167506/the-installation-window-dont-show-a-root-file-system-for-choose-in-the-installa & https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2437702

Comment: if any of the above suggestion doesn't work for you, then try to install any virtual machine software inside the windows operating system and create one virtual machine and then you can install ubuntu.

Comment: Let's see if it can help

Answer (score 3):

I had an interesting time installing Xubuntu on my new laptop.

I searched the internet, and found several answers to my problems, including a very good solution at this location:

```
forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?t=265615
```

Here is an explanation on how I installed Xubuntu on an Acer Aspire 3 A317.

This may also work for other models of Aspire 3 laptops, as well.

*NOTE:  Acer may deny warranty on Aspire 3 laptops that have Linux installed by the end user.  They will only support the original OS provided with the laptop.*

When you first start the laptop, out of the box, DO NOT go through the Windoze set up.  You must make some changes in the BIOS first.

*NOTE:  If Windoze was set up before you make the changes to the BIOS, then it will not boot.  You may have to run a Windoze repair, in order to allow it to boot properly.*

**Step 1**
Disable Intel RST and set system to use AHCI.

Power on the laptop for the first time, and enter the BIOS using the F2 key.

In order to make and save changes in the BIOS, you must set a Supervisor Password.

In the BIOS, go to "Security" - Set Supervior Password
(I used a simple 4 digit PIN, as I am the only one who will be using the computer.)

Go to the BIOS "Main" to enable Supervisor privileges, buy pressing "ctrl-s".

Select the "SATA Mode" and change from "Intel Optane" to AHCI.

Also, disable Fast Boot.

**Step 2**
Check your BIOS version.
It must be version 1.17 or later.  If it is not, you must go through the Windoze setup to upgrade it.

*If you already have version 1.17, skip this step and go to Step 3.*

Save the BIOS changes and boot into Windoze set up.

Do not connect a network cable to the laptop.

During setup, you can disable Cortana (Optional).

At the Network screen, in the bottom left corner, tell setup that you have NO INTERNET.

Select minimal options for Windoze.

Provide a user name and password.  The password can be optional, if you do not intend to use dual boot, as you will be erasing Windoze anyway.

You can now boot into Windoze and connect to your network.

Go to Acer Support and obtain the latest version of you BIOS.

Download and install the update.

Allow the system to boot back to Windoze, to ensure that BIOS update completes properly.

**Step 3**
If you intend to use Dual Boot, you must resize the storage partition on the hard drive.
Do not use gparted.

You must use the native Windoze disk manager.

*If you have not done so, go through the Windoze setup, as described in Step 2.
If you do not want to save Windoze, skip this step and go to Step 4.*

Open "Computer Management" in Windoze, and select the "Disk Management Tool".

Select the storage partition, (it's the largest partition on the disk.)

Shrink the partition to provide enough space to install Xubuntu.

**Step 4**
Set your install media as a trusted boot device in the BIOS.

Insert your installation USB into the laptop.

Restart the laptop and enter the BIOS using F2.

Go to the "Security" tab, "Select an UEFI file as trusted for executing" *(Acer's grammatical error, not mine!)*

Navigate to USB0\EFI\ubuntu\grubx64.efi and add it as a trusted boot option.

Go to the "Boot" tab and select the USB as the primary boot option.

Save changes and exit the BIOS.

**Step 5**
Boot the laptop with the USB install media, and install your favourite flavour of Ubuntu.

I prefer Xubuntu, with my own customized xfce desktop.

Post install, reboot the laptop, and go back into the BIOS.

Add HDD0\EFI\ubuntu\grubx64.efi as a trusted boot option in the "Security" tab, and set it as primary in the "Boot" tab.

Cheers!

Naught.

Acer Aspire 3 17.3" Laptop - Intel Core i5-1035G1/512GB SSD/8GB RAM A317-52-58ZK

Answer (score 0):

Thank you guys for all the help however I discovered a thread on Acer support that's currently having the same issue as me. They believe it's due to laptop firmware not being supported by ubuntu. Thanks for the help I'll post a link here

https://community.acer.com/en/discussion/589603/linux-live-usb-doesnt-detect-hdd-on-aspire-3-a315-56

edit: just read through the thread again, they found a fix :)

Comment: Please [edit] your answer to add the fix you found. Link-only answers are not useful if the content that the link points to gets removed for some reason.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu. This is a question answer site. You are most welcome to answer your own question. However, the answer should be free standing and not depend on a link. Please list how to fix the problem and give the link as a reference. After the mandatory wait period please accept your answer as correct by clicking on the gray check mark ✔️ and turn it green ✅. This will indicate the problem is solved and help others