# HDD disk is not detecting

Tags: hard-drive, disk

I have installed Ubuntu 20.04 to my Acer aspire 3. Windows 10 was preinstalled to hdd and I bought ssd and installed ubuntu to my new ssd and currently ubuntu is not detecting my hdd , I think it is because of windows 10 installed to my hdd , and I can easly use windows with pushing f12 while it restarts and choosing windows and I can switch OS to ubuntu with the same way. PLease help me how can I use hdd in ubuntu as well, thanks beforehand.

Comment: First thing, you probably want to check in your BIOS/UEFI that the ssd is the first device to boot. That should give you a grub menu with both Ubuntu and Windows on it. Then in Ubuntu, using a terminal execute the command lsblk and add the output to your question

Comment: Terminal detected my ssd but didn't find hdd

Comment: Are you saying the lsblk command did not show anything for the HDD? In Windows what does the disk manager show for the disk type for the HDD? It could be basic or dynamic. Does the HDD have an EFI partition? Could be one OS is legacy and the other UEFI.

Comment: 1) It showed only some partitions of hdd. Here is lsblk result (for some reason windows splited my hdd several partitions that is why thre are so many disks detected):

Comment: NAME        MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
loop0         7:0    0    26M  1 loop /run/miso/sfs/livefs
loop1         7:1    0 348.7M  1 loop /run/miso/sfs/mhwdfs
loop2         7:2    0   1.6G  1 loop /run/miso/sfs/desktopfs
loop3         7:3    0 679.3M  1 loop /run/miso/sfs/rootfs
sda           8:0    1  14.7G  0 disk /run/miso/bootmnt
├─sda1        8:1    1   2.6G  0 part 
└─sda2        8:2    1     4M  0 part 
nvme0n1     259:0    0 111.8G  0 disk 
├─nvme0n1p1 259:1    0    16M  0 part 
└─nvme0n1p2 259:2    0 111.8G  0 part

Comment: 2) It says online and I have a option to change it to dynamic
3)from cmd on windows I searched for this
DISKPART> list disk
Disk ###  Status         Size     Free     Dyn  Gpt
--------  -------------  -------  -------  ---  ---
Disk 0    Online          931 GB  1024 KB        *
Disk 1    Online          111 GB  1024 KB        *

Comment: P.S I have currently ssd(120gb)+hdd(1tb) on my laptop P.S 2 thanks for your help beforehand :)

Comment: Observations 1) Windows shows both disks. 2) sda looks like its a small usb drive in the region of 16GB. Were you in a live environment when you ran the lsblk command? 3) Your SSD (nvme0n1) is not mounted so you were not running Ubuntu on that disk when you ran the lsblk command. 4) the partitioning of the SSD looks odd for Ubuntu and could be the result of a legacy install. 5) I don't think your HDD is dynamic, which is good because Ubuntu cannot read it if it is. Don't attempt to change it, you can lose data if you do. @oldfred Do you have any comments?

Comment: 1) correct 2) correct 3)correct 4)I couldn't understand that but it seems correct 5) correct ok

Comment: Having done some research I think the issue here may be that your laptop does not use AHCI by default but uses Intel Optane and Intel RST. I don’t have hardware like this but I’m fairly sure Optane doesn’t work easily with Linux. Someone else has written a long answer to this issue here. https://askubuntu.com/questions/1287542/please-help-me-install-ubuntu-on-my-acer-aspire-3

Comment: Ok it seems it works with my laptop but unfortunately I cannot try it right now, but in the near future I will definitely try it thanks a lot for your effort have a nice one :)