# Ubuntu Can't be installed in my 1TB HDD with windows

Tags: 14.04

I have an acer Aspire 3, with a windows 10, I want to install linux and erase windows completely, when I tried the ubuntu installation said that "you need at least 8.6 GB to install" and that I only had 8GB, which are the size of the pen drive I'm using to boot the ISO, so it is not recognizing the HDD, then I switch from RAID to AHCI on windows, and tried again, still the same issue.

I have no idea why this is happening, can anyone help me figure this out?

Comment: Are you really trying 14.04? That has expired. You should be using 20.04 or maybe 18.04. Are you using latest UEFI from Acer. Many needed UEFI firmware update.  Acer Aspire A315-53-386P remove RAID from drive
https://askubuntu.com/questions/1167506/the-installation-window-dont-show-a-root-file-system-for-choose-in-the-installa Probably newer model: Acer Aspire 5 Model A515-54-5649  Intel Core i5-10210U Install Tutorial
https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2437702  Trust settings in step 35
http://askubuntu.com/questions/627416/acer-aspire-e15-will-not-dual-boot

Comment: Only supported releases of Ubuntu (*standard support*) are on-topic for this site.  Ubuntu 14.04 LTS is in extended support and now Ubuntu 14.04 ESM thus only supported by Canonical via Ubuntu Advantage and off-topic here.  Refer https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EOLUpgrades http://fridge.ubuntu.com/2019/05/02/ubuntu-14-04-trusty-tahr-reached-end-of-life-on-april-25-2019-esm-available/

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why does the Ubuntu installer not detect the hard drive during installation?](https://askubuntu.com/q/99038/)

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you can boot from a USB stick with a current version of the Ubuntu installation ISO (20.04 is an excellent choice, as noted), select the "Try Ubuntu" option from the initial startup screen, and run the **Disks** tool (this is in fact the superb GParted program) before you try to install.

**Disks** should list your 1 TB HDD on the left column; click on this item and you'll see a graphical representation of the partitions on your 1 TB HDD.

Because of these existing Windows partitions, this 1 TB HDD probably has very little or no free space available, which is why the Ubuntu installer won't install on it. Note that "free space," from the installer's perspective, is space on your HDD that isn't partitioned. So you may have a large Windows partition with lots of "free space" but since this space is already allocated to the Windows partition, the installer can't use it.

You can delete all of the partitions on this 1 TB volume to free up space for your Ubuntu installation, but that means that you'll lose all of the data and software on the 1 TB HDD. Before you do that,

- Make sure you've backed up any irreplaceable data files on the 1 TB HDD, because once you delete the partitions, that data is gone forever.
- Ensure that you can reach the Internet when you Try Ubuntu. You can test this by opening a browser and trying to reach, say, Google or Stack Exchange. Installing Ubuntu to an internal HDD is much easier if you can download the most recent updates during the installation process.

If you're ready to clear off the 1 TB HDD, **Disks** will let you select and delete each existing partition. Note that none of the commands you issue in the Disks program will be applied until you confirm that you want to proceed; then all of them will be executed in the sequence you specified, as a batch job.

After you've deleted all the partitions on the 1 TB HDD, you can exit Disks and run the Install Ubuntu program on the desktop, or reboot from the USB stick and select the Install Ubuntu option when it boots up. Now the installer should see all of the free space on your 1 TB HDD, and install accordingly.

Note that you can also use Disks to resize partitions and set up a dual-boot system if you still want to use Windows, or even install Ubuntu as a program you run after you boot Windows. These options are more complex, and not what you indicated you wanted to do, but may be worth considering if you want to preserve your Windows setup for now.

If, for any reason, Disks reports errors when it tries to delete or resize a partition, this means your HDD has some serious problems and should be replaced.

Comment: If you want to run Windows again DO NOT mess with a Windows partition with a Ubuntu tool. Go into Windows and shrink the partition from there.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, disks didnt list the hdd at first, then, after I close and open the laptop the 1tb hdd would appear there, I just closed and opened it right after, then I could erase the partition and install linix, but only after closing and openong the notebook. Now I got it installed but there is an error that drops me to a shell, I’m trying some things, but I might open another question for it

Comment: Sounds like you might have some hardware issues with the HDD, especially if it's not appearing consistenly in the Disks listing column. Another option is to replace the HDD with an SSD -- this will vastly improve the performance of the computer overall. I just picked up a 1 TB SSD for $100 USD, and you can get a smaller SSD for much less. A 256 GB SDD will give you plenty of space for data, as Ubuntu only requires 20 - 30 GB for a full installation.